# Select From DataTable with Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select a row from a datatable with a certain account number and the most recent date before or equal to a set datetime. I want the below but only the latest entry so it seems I want to use FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() after currentDateTime (ie... <= currentDateTime.FirstOrDefault())

```
DateTime currentDateTime = firstDate;
while (firstDate <= lastDate)
{
     foreach (AccountCategory a in db.AccountCategories)
     {
         var result = Settings.dtCurrent.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(b => b.Field<string>("Account") == a.Account 
                         && (b.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= currentDateTime);
     }
}
```

The above doesn't give me the most recent entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
    DateTime currentDateTime = firstDate;
    while (firstDate <= lastDate)
    {
         foreach (AccountCategory a in db.AccountCategories)
         {
             var result = Settings.dtCurrent.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(b => b.Field<string>("Account") == a.Account 
                             && (b.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= currentDateTime).OrderByDescending(b=> b.Field<DateTime>("Date")).FirstOrDefault();


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort the record to get the lestest on top. You can then get the first using [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get first record.

```
foreach (AccountCategory a in db.AccountCategories)
{
     var result = Settings.dtCurrent.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(b => b.Field<string>("Account") == a.Account 
                     && (b.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= currentDateTime).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DateTime currentDateTime = firstDate;
    while (firstDate <= lastDate)
    {
         foreach (AccountCategory a in db.AccountCategories)
         {
             var result = Settings.dtCurrent.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(b => b.Field<string>("Account") == a.Account 
                             && (b.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= currentDateTime)
                   .OrderByDescending(b=> b.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
         }
    }
```